# Connecting to RavenDb using Java Client with username and password

Tags: spring, ravendb

I was able to connect to RavenDb as described [here](https://github.com/ravendb/jvm-client/blob/master/Samples/Raven.Sample.Java.Todo.Spring/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml). But I could not pass the credentials (username/password) when it is required for a connection. How do I do that using a Java client? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Windows authentication is not supported by RavenDB java client.

However it supports OAuth authentication.

For more details see here: http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/java/client-api/how-to/work-with-authentication